# Move upsell after product description using xml

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I am trying to move the up-sell block below the the description tabs
I have this so far

**app/design/frontend/THEME/main/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="content" after="-"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

When i refresh the cache i get no up-sell block at all. Everything else keeps working as expected.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is already below the description tabs. Where you want to move upsell block could you please screenshot with me

[image]